# A better `:browse` command (GHCi)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'd like to write a GHCi macro that augments `:browse` by filtering the list of results (basically, a simple `grep` for `:browse:` output). For example, to see all output that includes the word `Monad`:

```
 Prelude> :mybrowse Prelude Monad
 (=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
 class Monad m where
 mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
 mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
 sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]
 sequence_ :: Monad m => [m a] -> m ()
 Prelude>
```

I can't see a way to implement this using `:def`. Is there a way?

Comment: I assume you know about `:i`?

Comment: Yes. Maybe a better example would show all functions that take [a] arguments. I'll update.

Comment: You could install hoogle locally.

Comment: I've googled around and tried some things, but it doesn't look like it's possible to capture the output of one GHCi command on pipe it into another.  This feature has been requested a few times, so you might be able to bring it up again and see if someone has the chance to implement it.  Otherwise, you'll have to figure out how to `browse` a module yourself, which may be difficult.

Comment: There are probably some packages out there that can get a module's export list pretty easily, you could use one of those and implement the functionality yourself, but it's going to be nontrivial

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to get access to the current GHCi session from within the macro?

Comment: I'd say your best bet is to look into using `hint`.  You can easily get the exports of a module with [`getModuleExports`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint-0.3.3.7/docs/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:getModuleExports), and then get information about each with `typeOf` and `kindOf`.  It'll take a lot of work, though.  I'd recommend writing another module to simplify it, then importing that into your `ghci.rc` and using `:def` there.  Otherwise you'll be having to write rather length and complex functions without the aid of whitespace, which is just not fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did something like this (and a bit more) a few years ago and wrote it up as a tutorial. No idea whether it'll still work, but have a look

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Ghci#Using_.ghci.2C_a_mini-tutorial

Comment: The mail you link to (http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-September/032260.html) actually contains a definition of `grep`! Did you write that original as well? @claus

Comment: @JustinBailey yes, that was my email:-)